# Unable to scrape two types of names from a website using the requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've created a script in Python to scrape two types of names from a [webpage](https://dallas.tx.publicsearch.us/results?_docTypes=AMD%2CDT%2CMOD%2CMODT%2CDE%2CCORR%20DT&department=RP&limit=50&offset=0&recordedDateRange=20181101%2C20231010&searchOcrText=true&searchType=quickSearch&searchValue=%22adjustable%20rate%20rider%22) using the requests module. I wish to grab the names under the `GRANTOR` and `GRANTEE` columns.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://dallas.tx.publicsearch.us/results?_docTypes=AMD%2CDT%2CMOD%2CMODT%2CDE%2CCORR%20DT&department=RP&limit=50&offset=0&recordedDateRange=20181101%2C20231010&searchOcrText=true&searchType=quickSearch&searchValue=%22adjustable%20rate%20rider%22'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select("[data-tourid='searchResults'] table > tbody > tr"):
    grantor = item.select("td")[3].text
    grantee = item.select("td")[4].text
    print(grantor,grantee)
```

When I run the script, it yields nothing.

Comment: Since you're not getting what you want in `grantor` and `grantee` take one step back, what are you getting on `item`, what are you getting on `res.text`.

Comment: Also check `soup.getText(separator='\n')` which "usually" will return all text that is visible to the user.

Comment: the information on this page is received from websocket, use selenium or websockets lib

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that the data you see is being loaded after the initial page load. Therefore using `requests` against the URL you have specified returns only the HTML contents of the initial page; it will not show any data that JavaScript code that is then executing subsequently might download. However, you can use the `selenium` package to screen scrape the data. Here I am using the Chrome browser and waiting up to 15 seconds for elements with class 'col-3' and 'col-4' to appear (holding grantor and grantee data respectively). You will need to download a `ChromeDriver` appropriate for the current release of Chrome you are using and place it in a directory that is specified by your environment's PATH value. You can, of course, use a different browser such as Firefox and download a suitable selenium driver for that. The code will then require Firefox-specific changes.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(15)

    driver.get('https://dallas.tx.publicsearch.us/results?_docTypes=AMD%2CDT%2CMOD%2CMODT%2CDE%2CCORR%20DT&department=RP&limit=50&offset=0&recordedDateRange=20181101%2C20231010&searchOcrText=true&searchType=quickSearch&searchValue=%22adjustable%20rate%20rider%22')

    grantors = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'col-3')
    grantees = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'col-4')
    l = len(grantors)
    for idx in range(l):
        print(f'grantor: {grantors[idx].text}, grantee: {grantees[idx].text}')
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Prints:

```
NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO
NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
HIXSON IRENA LEIGH HIXSON IRENA LEIGH
NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
EVANS LYNN DAVID EVANS LYNN DAVID
GUMP ROBERT MICHAEL GUMP ROBERT MICHAEL
BLOCH RAFAEL BLOCH RAFAEL
MCDUFFIE CHAD MICHAEL MCDUFFIE CHAD MICHAEL
NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
NEWHAM CAROLYN A NEWHAM CAROLYN A
GUINN JOSHUA DOUGLAS GUINN JOSHUA DOUGLAS
NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
BLACKSON BRONSON ADAM BLACKSON BRONSON ADAM
NEWHAM CAROLYN A NEWHAM CAROLYN A
BETTE MEERA RAO BETTE MEERA RAO
BRENNER LISA MARQUIS BRENNER LISA MARQUIS
BRUNO ROBERT A BRUNO ROBERT A
BLOCH RAFAEL BLOCH RAFAEL
ALLEN LETTY LAMKIN ALLEN LETTY LAMKIN
GLOGAU ALEXANDER IVES GLOGAU ALEXANDER IVES
NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
LERMAN ELAINE DRUSS LERMAN ELAINE DRUSS
DOHERTY ALLISON B DOHERTY ALLISON B
NEERMAN JONATHAN DANNY NEERMAN JONATHAN DANNY
DABNEY CHARLENE DABNEY CHARLENE
DICKEY ALLISON DICKEY ALLISON
FARR JAMES L FARR JAMES L
GIBBONS LUKE AARON GIBBONS LUKE AARON
HOLLAND JOHN THOMAS HOLLAND JOHN THOMAS
MILLER GABRIEL WELLS FARGO BANK
HEATH LYNN D HEATH LYNN D
NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
DUCATE JEFFREY STEWART DUCATE JEFFREY STEWART
GUPTA AMISH VIREN GUPTA AMISH VIREN
NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
GUPTA AMISH VIREN GUPTA AMISH VIREN
MCDUFFIE CHAD MICHAEL MCDUFFIE CHAD MICHAEL
NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO
NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO
JOHNSON DARRIEL LOYD JR JOHNSON DARRIEL LOYD JR
LERMAN ELAINE DRUSS LERMAN ELAINE DRUSS
DOUGLASS GREGORY K AKA WELLS FARGO BANK NA
NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO
KHAN FAIZA WELLS FARGO BANK NA
FIRST NATIONAL BANK OF CENTRAL TEXAS FIRST NATIONAL BANK OF CENTRAL TEXAS
ILYAS HAARISS UIF CORPORATION
JOSEPH LISSY INDEPENDENT BANK
SOLIS MARIA RITA ENNIS STATE BANK
```

**Downloading All The Pages**

Here is code using Firefox that will loop through all the pages of data and print out just the first row on each page. Note that I have tried doing this with Chrome and Edge and they both seem to hang after having processed a variable number of pages.

The idea is to click on the "Next Page" button so long as it can be found on the page, then wait for the button to become "stale" (i.e. no longer exists on the page, signifying a new page has started to download, and only then to look for new data. Note also that I have not specified any driver options to be in "headless" mode (i.e. you will see the browser will be visible as it pages through the data):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

class WaitUntilElementIsStale:
    def __init__(self, *, driver=None, element=None, timeout=10):
        assert driver or element
        self.element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html') if element is None else element
        self.timeout = timeout

    def __enter__(self):
        return None

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        if exc_type is not None:
            return
        start_time = time.time()
        while time.time() < start_time + self.timeout:
            try:
                # poll the link with an arbitrary call
                self.element.find_elements(By.ID, "doesn't-matter")
            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                return
            time.sleep(0.1)
        raise Exception('Timeout waiting for page load')

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(15)

    driver.get('https://dallas.tx.publicsearch.us/results?_docTypes=AMD%2CDT%2CMOD%2CMODT%2CDE%2CCORR%20DT&department=RP&limit=50&offset=0&recordedDateRange=20181101%2C20231010&searchOcrText=true&searchType=quickSearch&searchValue=%22adjustable%20rate%20rider%22')

    page_no = 0
    while True:
        page_no += 1
        grantors = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'col-3')
        grantees = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'col-4')
        print(f'page: {page_no}, grantor: {grantors[0].text}, grantee: {grantees[0].text}')
        next = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/article/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/nav/div/button[12]')
        if not next:
            break
        with WaitUntilElementIsStale(driver=driver, element=next, timeout=15):
            WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(next)).click()
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Prints:

```None
page: 1, grantor: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO, grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
page: 2, grantor: HOLLAND JASON, grantee: INDEPENDENT BANK
page: 3, grantor: MAPLEHILL RESIDENTIAL LLC, grantee: MAPLEHILL RESIDENTIAL LLC
page: 4, grantor: BERNARD CASSIAN PAUL, grantee: BERNARD CASSIAN PAUL
page: 5, grantor: NERENBERG AMY, grantee: CADENCE BANK
page: 6, grantor: GUPTA AMISH VIREN, grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO
page: 7, grantor: HALL CAM, grantee: THE BANK OF MISSOURI
page: 8, grantor: SMALLWOOD GREGORY C, grantee: BANCORPSOUTH BANK
page: 9, grantor: ALBA GARY JOHN, grantee: CADENCE BANK
...
page: 194, grantor: SONI SHAMEER A, grantee: U S BANK NATIONAL ASSOCIATION
page: 195, grantor: SINGH AKSHAY, grantee: U S BANK NATIONAL ASSOCIATION
page: 196, grantor: AARONSON MAXINE, grantee: AARONSON MAXINE
page: 197, grantor: FLAGSTAR BANK, grantee: FLAGSTAR BANK
page: 198, grantor: REED CHRISTY AKA, grantee: REED CHRISTY AKA
page: 199, grantor: NIEMANN BRIAN, grantee: NIEMANN BRIAN
page: 200, grantor: MANOR STANLEY DAPHNE REY, grantee: MANOR STANLEY DAPHNE REY
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 45, in <module>
    print(f'page: {page_no}, grantor: {grantors[0].text}, grantee: {grantees[0].text}')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Note the exception due to not finding the sought data. When I manually paged through the data and tried to load page 201, I got:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.get('https://dallas.tx.publicsearch.us/results?_docTypes=AMD%2CDT%2CMOD%2CMODT%2CDE%2CCORR%20DT&department=RP&limit=50&offset=0&recordedDateRange=20181101%2C20231010&searchOcrText=true&searchType=quickSearch&searchValue=%22adjustable%20rate%20rider%22')
table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"main-content\"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody")
rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
for row in rows:
    grantor = row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "col-3").text
    grantee = row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "col-4").text
    print(f"Grantor: {grantor} Grantee: {grantee}")
```

**Output:**

```
Grantor: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO Grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
Grantor: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO Grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
Grantor: NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO Grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO
Grantor: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO Grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
Grantor: HIXSON IRENA LEIGH Grantee: HIXSON IRENA LEIGH
Grantor: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO Grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
Grantor: EVANS LYNN DAVID Grantee: EVANS LYNN DAVID
Grantor: GUMP ROBERT MICHAEL Grantee: GUMP ROBERT MICHAEL
Grantor: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO Grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
Grantor: GUINN JOSHUA DOUGLAS Grantee: GUINN JOSHUA DOUGLAS
Grantor: BLACKSON BRONSON ADAM Grantee: BLACKSON BRONSON ADAM
Grantor: NEWHAM CAROLYN A Grantee: NEWHAM CAROLYN A
Grantor: BETTE MEERA RAO Grantee: BETTE MEERA RAO
Grantor: BLOCH RAFAEL Grantee: BLOCH RAFAEL
Grantor: MCDUFFIE CHAD MICHAEL Grantee: MCDUFFIE CHAD MICHAEL
Grantor: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO Grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
Grantor: BRUNO ROBERT A Grantee: BRUNO ROBERT A
Grantor: BLOCH RAFAEL Grantee: BLOCH RAFAEL
Grantor: ALLEN LETTY LAMKIN Grantee: ALLEN LETTY LAMKIN
Grantor: GLOGAU ALEXANDER IVES Grantee: GLOGAU ALEXANDER IVES
Grantor: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO Grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
Grantor: BRENNER LISA MARQUIS Grantee: BRENNER LISA MARQUIS
Grantor: MCDUFFIE CHAD MICHAEL Grantee: MCDUFFIE CHAD MICHAEL
Grantor: NEERMAN JONATHAN DANNY Grantee: NEERMAN JONATHAN DANNY
Grantor: DABNEY CHARLENE Grantee: DABNEY CHARLENE
Grantor: DOHERTY ALLISON B Grantee: DOHERTY ALLISON B
Grantor: DICKEY ALLISON Grantee: DICKEY ALLISON
Grantor: FARR JAMES L Grantee: FARR JAMES L
Grantor: GIBBONS LUKE AARON Grantee: GIBBONS LUKE AARON
Grantor: MILLER GABRIEL Grantee: WELLS FARGO BANK
Grantor: HOLLAND JOHN THOMAS Grantee: HOLLAND JOHN THOMAS
Grantor: NEWHAM CAROLYN A Grantee: NEWHAM CAROLYN A
Grantor: LERMAN ELAINE DRUSS Grantee: LERMAN ELAINE DRUSS
Grantor: HEATH LYNN D Grantee: HEATH LYNN D
Grantor: DUCATE JEFFREY STEWART Grantee: DUCATE JEFFREY STEWART
Grantor: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO Grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
Grantor: GUPTA AMISH VIREN Grantee: GUPTA AMISH VIREN
Grantor: GUPTA AMISH VIREN Grantee: GUPTA AMISH VIREN
Grantor: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO Grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK&TRUST CO
Grantor: NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO Grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO
Grantor: NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO Grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO
Grantor: JOHNSON DARRIEL LOYD JR Grantee: JOHNSON DARRIEL LOYD JR
Grantor: LERMAN ELAINE DRUSS Grantee: LERMAN ELAINE DRUSS
Grantor: NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO Grantee: NORTH DALLAS BANK & TRUST CO
Grantor: KHAN FAIZA Grantee: WELLS FARGO BANK NA
Grantor: DOUGLASS GREGORY K AKA Grantee: WELLS FARGO BANK NA
Grantor: FIRST NATIONAL BANK OF CENTRAL TEXAS Grantee: FIRST NATIONAL BANK OF CENTRAL TEXAS
Grantor: ILYAS HAARISS Grantee: UIF CORPORATION
Grantor: JOSEPH LISSY Grantee: INDEPENDENT BANK
Grantor: GOYNE JO A Grantee: TEXAS SECURITY BANK
```